# Error: "too few arguements in template class name 'queue' " in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I am a novice and I want to implement a simple queue using STL in C++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<queue>

int main(){
    std::queue <int> myqu;
    int myarr[10] = { 0};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        myarr[i] = i*2;
        myqu.push(myarr[i]);
        }
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        cout << myqu.pop(myarr[i])<<"\n";
    }
    getchar();
    }
```

On compiling, i am getting this error "too few arguements in template class name 'queue' " on line 7.

Comment: `std::queue<int> myqu;` should be fine. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Lint 7 is `int myarr[10] = ...`. Could you pose real code? Also, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Also note that [`std::queue::pop()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop) doesn't return anything (or take an argument), so you can't print it. You probably want [`front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/front) instead, and then to `pop()` separately.

Comment: @juanchopanza Borland C++

Comment: It turns out that my compiler did not support queue and as answered by @songyuanyao the correct syntax will be `std::queue<int, std::deque<int> > myqu;` . And there are mistakes with front and pop too.

Comment: @explorer I was half expecting that answer, sadly. Please consider switching to a [compiler from this century](https://isocpp.org/get-started).

Answer (score 2):

`std::queue <int> myqu;` is perfectly fine. It seems that the error message is not right. However, you have some other problems in your code. This is how you `pop` from a `queue`:

```
auto value = myqu.front();
myqu.pop();
```

This is your final program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <queue>

int main(){
    std::queue <int> myqu;
    int myarr[10] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        myarr[i] = i*2;
        myqu.push(myarr[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        myarr[i]=myqu.front();
        std::cout<< myarr[i] <<"\n";
        myqu.pop();
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/86jz5)

Comment: Might like to make `<stdio.h>` into `<cstdio>` too, though some people will argue about that one.

Answer (score 1):

Queue creation is already correct, but if you compiler still complains(which i doubt), you can add then the default parameter alse

Also, queue.pop() does not return anything, So you cannot print anything and compiler should complain that too..

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
   // mostly not needed
   std::queue <int,std::deque<int> > myqu;
   int myarr[10];

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      myarr[i] = i*2;
      myqu.push(myarr[i]);
   }

   while(!myqu.empty())
   {
      cout << myqu.front()<<"\n";
      myqu.pop();
   }
   // Note the quete will be empty here
   getchar();
}
```